# I have a site having a url 'http//:abc.xyz.com/profile/ray' and want to change this url to 'www.ray.loyal.build ' (change the url to dynamic url)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site having the following url :

```
http//:abc.xyz.com/profile/ray
```

I want to change my url to " `www.ray.loyal.build` " like this for home page

and for other pages like about-us ,faq the Url should be

```
www.ray.loyal.build/about-us 
www.ray.loyal.build/faq respectivily
```

where ray is dymanic,its a name of person.

I am already using a htacess code :

```
<IfModulemod_rewrite.c><br>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?section=$1&action=$2&var1=$3&var2=$4&var3=$5&var4=$6&var5=$7&var6=$8&var7=$9& [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

this code is for other things.
How can i change my site url to dynamic one including the above htaccess code?

I am new in htacess. Please help.

Comment: hey maybe this url can help http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html